# Limit and adherent points of the union of sets $H = ({\frac{1}{n}}) \times (\frac{n-1}{2n} , \frac{n+1}{2n})$ in $R^2$

Tags: general-topology

Firstly of all set $({\frac{1}{n}})$ a has limit point zero.

Then $(\frac{n-1}{2n} , \frac{n+1}{2n})$ for all $n$ at every $({\frac{1}{n}})$ has infinitely many limit points. But if $n$ approach infinity, then from both side it goes towards $1/2$.

So there is only one limit point: $ ({0}) \times (\frac{1}{2})?$

I am a bit confused how can I combine all this mess together.

Can you help me with it?

Comment: Is H subset R^3 or R^2?

Comment: @WilliamElliot in $R^2$

Comment: Explain in your title the use of ×.  (1/n) is not a set.  "Then .... " is  very confusing.  What is (0)×(1/2)?  Do you mean the point (0,1) in R^2?

Comment: @WilliamElliot I meant the point (0;1/2) in $R^2$

Comment: Are you asking what are the limit points of { ((2n-1)/n,  (2n+1)/n) in R^2 : n in N }?

Comment: @WilliamElliot No, I am asking what are limit points of the union of vertical intervals $({\frac{1}{n}}) \times (\frac{n-1}{2n} , \frac{n+1}{2n})$ in $R^2$

Comment: Your notation is incomprehensible.  Do you want the limit points of the union of { {n} × ((2n-1)/n, (2n+1)/n) : n  in N }?   Then you need to write it all out instead quick glib meaningless stuff that gets you ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each $n\in\Bbb N$ put $I_n=\{\frac 1n\}\times \left(\frac {n-1}{2n};\frac {n+1}{2n}\right)$. I assume that you are asking on the set $A’$ of limit points of a set $A=\bigcup I_n$. Since the set $A$ has no isolated points, $A’=\overline{A}$. It is easy to check that $x_0=(0,\frac 12)\in\overline{A}$ and each point $x\in\Bbb R^2$ different from $x_0$ has a neighborhood intersecting at most one of the segments $I_n$. So all  of the set $\overline{A}$ different from $x_0$ belong to a closure of a some set $I_n$. Thus $\overline{A}=\{x_0\}\cup\bigcup\overline{I_n}=\{(0,\frac 12)\}\cup\bigcup\{\frac 1n\}\times\left[\frac {n-1}{2n};\frac {n+1}{2n}\right]$.